# How do I fix my SSH configuration to use git behind an SSH proxy?

Tags: linux, git, ssh, proxy

So I'm currently in a situation where I have two SSH servers that both must be served over port 443 from behind a Linux router running Tomato.

To make this work, I have an SSH server on the router that acts as a relay to wherever I want to actually connect.

The `.ssh/config` file on the machine I'm connecting from looks like this:

```
Host destination
  HostName <internal IP of destination behind router>
  User gogs
  Port 22
  IdentityFile "<my identity file path>"
  ProxyCommand ssh -q relay -W %h:%p
  IdentitiesOnly yes

Host relay
  HostName <my domain name>
  User relay
  Port 443
  IdentityFile "<my identity file path>"
```

So this works fine for SSH, SCP, and even `git clone`, but literally none of the other git commands seem to work.

When I do `get fetch` without the `-q` flag on the `ProxyCommand`, it hangs for a second and says `Killed by signal 1`.

All the other solutions I've seen require using different proxy commands like `nc` command or `corkscrew`. The router I have is pretty much limited to the commands it comes with, and neither of those two are available.

Any ideas on how I can make this work, or at least an explanation of why what I'm trying to do doesn't work?

Thanks!

Comment: did you try netcat? (`nc`) version of proxy command?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I have the router setup so that the shell of the `relay` user cannot be used, so configuring it to allow the `nc` command is rather complicated. Regardless, it turns out the configuration I have does work and it was a mistake I made diagnosing the issue :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was mistaken and it actually was working the entire time. The `Killed by signal 1` thing is normal in the git command line unless you supply the `-q` flag to the SSH `ProxyCommand`, which I didn't have initially.

The confusion was due to the fact that I was using the IntelliJ IDE. IntelliJ by default uses its own built in SSH client which unknowingly did not take my `.ssh/config` into account. Switching to the native SSH installation fixed everything.